# Error: client = boto3.client('s3') | AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3

I'm working on the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment. I have a simple application to process images by downloading from S3 Bucket & upload to another S3 Bucket.

When I update the code I get the error in ***/var/log/httpd/error_log***

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback

**Please find the error log:**

[image]

**My Code Snippet:**

[image]

I faced no errors while working with AWS SES using boto

*import boto.ses*

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Your import statement doesn't look like you are importing boto3.

Comment: hi @MarkB please find the code snippet attached above. 
I have imported the boto3 library. 
In the requirements.txt file, I added the boto3 to make sure its installed.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem.

I don't have a good understanding of the problem, but I was able to unblock myself by pinning the version of the futures module to a working version.

For example, (in requirements.txt)

```
futures==2.2.0
```

The info that I have, I got from here:
https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/pull/387