# Can't create s3 resource/client in boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

EDIT: I believe this traceback stems from some sort of issue with the dependencies. Using pip to upgrade the packages didn't work but I created a new folder and installed from scratch and that worked out

I'm a Python novice so I'm struggling to debug an AWS Lambda I'm writing.

I've narrowed it down to this line of code `s3_client = botoSession.resource('s3')`, which is giving a long traceback with Syntax Error: invalid syntax. The botoSession variable is just for the credentials - `botoSession = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_token, aws_secret_access_token)`.

I've also tried `s3_client = boto3.client('s3')`, `s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')`, `s3_client = botoSession.resource('s3')`.

When I used `botoSession.client('ses', region)` I had no issues sending emails.

I found [Error: client = boto3.client('s3') | AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978851/error-client-boto3-clients3-aws-elastic-beanstalk-worker-environment) which appeared to be a similar issue, but it appeared to be fairly old and I wasn't able to figure out what the solution was. I tried adding 
`import sys
sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if not p.endswith('futures-3.0.3-py3.4.egg')]`
to the top of my file which didn't seem to work.

The entire traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smartsheetExporter.py", line 45, in <module>
    s3_client = botoSession.resource('s3')
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/boto3/session.py", line 389, in resource
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/botocore/session.py", line 836, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/botocore/client.py", line 65, in create_client
    cls = self._create_client_class(service_name, service_model)
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/botocore/client.py", line 90, in _create_client_class
    base_classes=bases)
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/boto3/utils.py", line 61, in _handler
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/boto3/utils.py", line 52, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 15, in <module>
    from boto3.s3.transfer import create_transfer_manager
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 127, in <module>
    from s3transfer.exceptions import RetriesExceededError as \
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/s3transfer/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/Users/nihar/LocalDocs/PythonPractice/Smartsheet-Emailer-Lambda/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 381
    raise exception_type, self._exception, self._traceback
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever strange things are happening, it's always a good idea to update things:

```
sudo pip install pip --upgrade
sudo pip install boto --upgrade
sudo pip install boto3 --upgrade
sudo pip install awscli --upgrade
```

If you're using Python 3, try `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue with boto3 and ended up having to downgrade the Python version that my lambda was running from Python 3.6 to Python 2.7. If you're using Serverless Framework for this, your `serverless.yml` file looks like this.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  memorySize: 3008

cool_function:
    name: cool-function
    description: This lambda goes and performs magic.
    handler: cool_function.lambda_handler
    runtime: python2.7
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(4 hours)
    timeout: 180
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with **python 3.6** and **AWS Lambda**.

I found another answer that helped me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978851/error-client-boto3-clients3-aws-elastic-beanstalk-worker-environment).

You should use `futures==2.2.0`

Answer (score -1):

If you are running your code **on an Amazon EC2 instance with a Role assigned** to the instance, then you only need this:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3') # Pick whichever is wish to use
```

If you are *not* on an Amazon EC2 instance, this works:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='AKIAxxx',aws_secret_access_key='yyy')
s3_client = session.client('s3')
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
```

Of course, you should **never put your credentials in the code file**. Instead, put them in a [credentials file](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html) (easiest is via `aws configure`) or in Environment Variables. That way, they won't be copied into any code repository.

See: [Boto3 credentials](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html)

Comment: Are the credentials causing the error/exception? I understand that I shouldn't have the credentials hard-coded in, but I was trying to just put together a working sample. I tried the code you suggested but I still have the same/similar traceback

Comment: When you aren't running on EC2 you can set those credentials as environment variables. That way the same code works in any environment.